# JNI error has occurred while adding to salesforce

Tags: java

When I launch my program with the following command:

```
java -classpath C:\SalesForce\wsc-master\force-wsc-38.0.3.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc path=C:\SalesForce\wsc-master\partner\partner.wsdl .\partner.jar
```

I get this error message:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Any ideas how to solve my problem?